# Unknot is the only knot that bounds a disk

Tags: algebraic-topology, differential-topology, knot-theory

I keep running across this statement, but how does one show that the only knot that bounds a disk is the trivial knot?

EDIT: I am seeking a more rigorous proof.

Comment: Take a small isotopy to ensure that the knot is a smooth embedding, then take an isotopy that looks like $f_t(x) = f(tx)/t$, using smoothness to extend it across the entire disk.

Comment: @anomaly Is $f$ describing the isotopy of the smoothly embedded knot to the standard unknot in $S^{3}$?

Comment: Yes.$\phantom{}$

Comment: How does smoothness allow the appropriate extension?

Comment: What happens at time $t = 0$?

Comment: @anomaly Why is $f_t$ a knot?

Comment: Why is $f_t$ an ambient isotopy? Just write out each $f_t:S^1 \to S^3$ for fixed $t$.

Comment: @MichaelShumate The proof of the more general statement is a three page paper by Palais available here ( http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1960-011-02/S0002-9939-1960-0117741-0/S0002-9939-1960-0117741-0.pdf ). If you are interested I suggest you read it.

Comment: @anomaly I don't understand. If we have the convention $f(1)=f(0)$ for instance , I don't think $f_t$ is ever closed for $t<1$.

Comment: I'm being lazy about writing out the details of $f$. The point is that this just Alexander's trick, once you manage to get the embedding to be $C^1$.